# how to setup and run golden tests on firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-integration-test

I have a flutter project with an integration test running a golden test:

```dart
void main() {
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('Screenshot test example', (tester) async {
    app_main.main(envFileName: 'assets/.test.env');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final bytes = await binding.takeScreenshot('screen1');

    await expectLater(
      bytes,
      matchesGoldenFile('goldens/screen1.png'),
    );
}
```

the test runs smoothly locally:

```
flutter test integration_test/trainings_test.dart -d C438207F-8765-4E3C-B785-C62FDBE39036
```

and I've followed [this guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing) in order to execute my test on firebase.
Everything is executed, but looking at the test logs the golden is skipped

```
May 19 20:23:47 iPhone Runner(Flutter)[419] <Notice>: flutter: Golden file comparison requested for "goldens/screen1.png"; skipping...
```

I'm wondering if and how

- I can pack my golden files along with the tests in order to make them run and pass correctly
- I can execute the golden on firebase. is that possible?